# Conditional loop for pandas dataframe rows

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe I've parsed out of a larger frame that looks like:

```
Contract Date
2012.0
2011.0
2011.0
2010.0
1312.0
1235.0
1235.0
1235.0
1230.0
.
.
111.0
111.0
110.0
110.0
```

I've converted the entire thing to strings so that I can slice the values because these dates are in a very strange format.

Basically the `2012.0 - 2010.0` are December of each year (2012 - 2010) but the dates like `1235.0` and `110.0` are in MMYY format - `1235.0` is Dec 2035 and `110.0` is Jan 2010.

What I want is to make a simple loop to iterate over these dates and translate them into months and year based off the conditions that I described above. I tried obtaining the month first using a poorly made attempt at using `iterrows`:

```
for index, row in contract.iterrows():
    if len(row) > 4:
        contract['Month'] = contract['Contract_Exp_Date'].str[:2]
    else:
        contract['Month'] = contract['Contract_Exp_Date'].str[:1]
```

But this did not work and loops for an exaggerated amount of time - probably because I need to be `appending` to a new column and not creating a new column `Month` every iteration.

How can I loop through each row and scrape both the month and the year based off the conditions I mentioned above correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need condition, just use logic of everything but last three characters, so logic written:

```
2018.0
   ^^^
   removed
111.0
  ^^^
  removed
```

So use:

```
df['Contract']=df['Contract'].str[:-3]
```

And now:

```
print(df['Contract'])
```

Is:

```
0     201
1     201
2     201
3     201
4     131
5     123
6     123
7     123
8     123
9      11
10     11
11     11
12     11
Name: Contract, dtype: object
```